# How to effeciently create index in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I want to create an Index on `Id` of my table. It's a `bigint`.

I would like to know what is the most good to have this index so that I can retrieve the data as fast as possible.

For example : 
`CREATE INDEX id_index ON lookup (id) USING BTREE;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wit respect, you're overthinking this. It happens that InnoDB and MyISAM tables only support BTREE indexes. If you have `MEMORY`  table you could create the index `USING HASH` but this is probably an ordinary table.

```
  CREATE INDEX id_index ON lookup (id);
```

gets you what you want.